# React state object attribute is getting set as undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following state object initialized called myCriteria

```
const [myCriteria, setMyCriteria] = useState({
    myFieldStatusDropdown: myFieldStatusDropdown,
    selectedMyFieldStatus: myVarMyFieldStatusDropdown?.value,
});
```

Now I have the breakpoint set right above this line

```
setMyCriteria({
    ...myCriteria,
    selectedMyFieldStatus: myCriteria.myFieldStatusDropdown[0]
});
```

and at the breakpoint, I inspect and see myCriteria.myFieldStatusDropdown as below

```
[
{
    code: 'Select',
    value: 'Select'
}, {
    code: 'AA',
    value: 'A 1'
}, {
    code: 'BB',
    value: 'B 1'
}
]
```

However for some strange reason, after the setMyCriteria line is executed, when I inspect the value of myCriteria.selectedMyFieldStatus, it is wrong
i.e. instead of it being set to

```
{
    code: 'Select',
    value: 'Select'
}
```

it is getting set as undefined

Not sure why it gets set as undefined

Comment: Where are you getting undefined?

Comment: I get myCriteria.selectedMyFieldStatus as undefined after the execution of the setter line of code

Comment: This is cuz setMyCriteria is Asynchronous, to see if the state change use an useEffect

Comment: Please share a [mcve] rather than little snippets taken out of context that can't be executed. You should probably be using an arrow function in your setter.

Answer (score 0):

I simply initialized using `myCriteria` and put three objects in it, in form of an array

```
 var myFieldStatusDropdown = [
    {
        code: 'Select',
        value: 'Select'
    }, {
        code: 'AA',
        value: 'A 1'
    }, {
        code: 'BB',
        value: 'B 1'
    }
]

 const [myCriteria, setMyCriteria] = useState({
    myFieldStatusDropdown: myFieldStatusDropdown,
    selectedMyFieldStatus: myFieldStatusDropdown[1]
});
```

then I use `setMyCriteria` to update the `myCriteria`

```
 setMyCriteria({
    ...myCriteria,
    selectedMyFieldStatus: myFieldStatusDropdown[0]
},[myCriteria]);
```